# Block cells without block the list

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to block cell without block list?
Ex: I have in cell A1 the list:

- Brazil
- USA
- Ireland

If I block the cell using "protect sheet"
I can't select the list

If I block on VBA using the code `application.cutcopymode = false`
It works, but if the person paste from a notepad, for example, it doesn't work

Is there any way to block it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
    If intersect(Target, range("A1")) is nothing then Exit Sub
    Application.CutCopyPaste = False
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do so (curious if I'm wrong).

What you could do however:

***1)*** Developers > Insert > Combobox

***2)*** Align Combobox with cell `A1`

***3)*** Assign the appropriate list and a linked cell

***4)*** On the Protection tab, select the Locked check box

***5)*** On linked cell make sure you deselect the Locked check box

***6)*** Protect your worksheet

Pasting values in cell A1 no longer possible, users deleting/moving/shaping your combobox is disabled AND you can still use the validation list :)